# Virtuemart upgrade/migrate 1 to 2

Tags: migration, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I had Joomla 1.5.23 running with virtuemart 1.1.9 and I have installed [jupgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) to move to 2.5 (because virtuemart does not support 3.x yet)
So now I have 2.5.14 with virtuemart 2.0.22c but then you need to move the products (and categories and orders)

So I followed this guide: http://emanipur.org/blog/item/157-migrate-virtuemart-119-to-2xx-without-losing-any-data which seems awesome. I have copied product images to a folder. enabled database update tools and in the migrationpanel let it migrate everything including the fly pages.

and then.... there was this error:
[image]
So there are still no products migrated, categories and products. So how should I migrate? I have joomla 1.5 and virtuemart1 running and in the jupgrade folder is the 2.5 with 2vm running.

ps. running php 5.3.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to start over. You should migrate VM first, then Joomla.

Everything you need is here - http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=95513.msg313625#msg313625

Comment: ok so jupgrade (which is recommended to move from joomla 1 to 2) is not the best option?

Comment: jUpgrade is a fine solution, but it's not designed to upgrade every extension you have installed. It would be impossible to account for every customization so it only moves the core components with some limited support for some popular extensions. You would use that AFTER upgrading VM in this case.

Comment: Also, if you have any other extensions installed, you would need to see is a) there is an upgrade available for it and b) the documentation on how to migrate that extension before starting. You will need to plan the entire upgrade out before starting and even then you may need to try a couple different times to get it to work.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I managed to remove all the jupgrade stuff and migrate vm1.x to 2.18x running on joomla 1.5 but when I jupgrade afterwards, the 2.5 joomla does not have virtuemart??

Comment: Correct, jUpgrade does not copy over the VM stuff. You should be able to install VM in your upgraded website, then copy the VM tables from your 1.5 site directly to the upgraded site.

Comment: All worked, but I lost the media. I moved the files by ftp to the new dir, but the products seem to have lost the image name. so the reference between product and image are gone.

Comment: You'll want to make sure that you have the images in the correct folder, I believe the location has changed for VM 2.0. Worst case scenario, use CSVI to process the images and add them back to the products. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/19745